# Terraform: Application load balancer complains of multiple subnets in AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am receiving this error

```
rror: Error creating application Load Balancer: InvalidConfigurationRequest: A load balancer cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same Availability Zone
    status code: 400, request id: cdbdcad5-c1be-4fc0-866f-1574ebe5bb59

  on main.tf line 67, in resource "aws_lb" "setup1":
  67: resource "aws_lb" "setup1" {
```

The setup of my subnets is one public, one private per AZ.

Here is the piece of the code that it refers to as wrong:

```
resource "aws_lb" "setup1" {

  name               = var.alb_name

  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets            = data.aws_subnet_ids.default.ids
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.alb.id]
}
```

I assume it only wants to reference my public subnet per AZ?

Thanks any help...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what I did that appeared to fix the issue:

The error in terraform was just pointing to I guess where it barffed. I went back to the subnets portions as you see here and just added the tag portion. prior to asking the question. I did not have this in the code.

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "default" { vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.vpc01-vpc.id
 tags = { Name = "public" } 
}
```

it appears to work, but it would be nice to know of other ways to fix the issue I had without using tags. I just happen to have my subnets/vpc and so on tagged really well so it was easy to fix once I figured this out.

Comment: Not sure why somehow downvoted when this is the solution. Only thing is I needed to manually tag my subnets and labeled my private subnets private so it worked only on our intranet...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error does not have anything to do with terraform as it is an ELB configuration issue. Please refer to the AWS ALB documentation which clearly specifies that within 1 availability zone, only 1 subnet can be associated with the ALB.  Same is also being pointed out in error message.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-subnets.html

> 5.To enable an Availability Zone, select the check box for that Availability Zone. If there is one subnet for that Availability Zone,
>   it is selected. If there is more than one subnet for that Availability
>   Zone, select one of the subnets. **Note that you can select only one
>   subnet per Availability Zone**